# Can't send keystrokes from Terminal to app using osascript in MacOS

Tags: terminal, keystroke, osascript

I have TextEdit open.
I want to enter "hello" in TextEdit, but not by typing it in myself, but using a command from Terminal.

I tried this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "TextEdit" to keystroke "hello"'
```

but it give the following error:

```
31:48: execution error: TextEdit got an error: Can’t get keystroke "hello". (-1728)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wrong application - **System Events** is the one that does keystrokes (check out the app’s scripting dictionary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

red_menace is right, this works:

```
osascript -e 'activate application "TextEdit"'; osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "hello"'
```